# Macros in python

Tags: python, macros, code-generation, macropy

in my project I have to repeat often such part of code:

```
class SimplePhysicObject(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Object, self).__init__('SimplePhysicObject')
```

But instead of `SimplePhysicObject` there is new string each time. Are there any ways to write some macro to make this work easier? Something like:

```
DoTemplate(NewObject)
==>
class NewObject(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Object, self).__init__('NewObject')
```

---

**UPD** Sorry, `Object` is my own class declared before in code

Comment: In every example you've given the string is also the name of the class. Is that always the case?

Comment: `Object` is not the object that goes there (also you may mean `object`). The object that goes there needs to be the *child* class (i.e., the one you're writing). So, `super(SimplePhysicsObject, self).whatever()`.

Comment: @Ockonal Why do you have `__init__`'s that take the names of classes (and the name of the class itself nonetheless)?

Comment: @Julian `Object` is my own type with constructor wich takes string. And I have to call that constructor from childrens (derivative classes)

Comment: Right, why though :)? Why does it need that string?

Comment: @Julian I'm writing main application in c++ and that's some info for log managers :)

Comment: This does feel like an X-Y problem. @Ockonal you may have better luck if you describe what you're ultimately trying to do, instead of just some python on which you're stuck along the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see a reason why `Object` should need the actual class name as a parameter.  You can access the actual class name in `Object` via `self.__class__.__name__`:

```
class Object(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = self.__class__.__name__

class SimplePhysicObject(Object):
    pass

a = SimplePhysicObject()
print a.name
```

will print

```
SimplePhysicObject
```

This is slightly different than your original code: If you derive from `SimplePhysicObject`, the `name` attribute will be set to the name of the derived class, whereas your original code would continue to use `"SimplePhysicObject"`.

Comment: Given the OP's reason that it's for logging, there may not even be a need to have an attribute at all other than `self.__class__.__name__`, but as given these answers are good now. +1.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the argument to `super(…).__init__` isn't hard. It's getting the class object as the argument to `super` itself that is best handled manually:

```
class SimplePhysicObject(Object):
    def __init__(self):
        cls = SimplePhysicObject
        super(cls, self).__init__(cls.__name__)
```

Comment: -1. This is broken. You need the actual name of the class in which the method is defined for `super` to work.

Comment: @Julian It's broken in the OP too

Comment: Well then I'll be sure to let the OP know that as well :).

Comment: @millimoose: But this one is even more broken than the original code.  `self.__class__.__name__` can easily point to a different class than the current one.

Comment: @Julian good catch. I've fixed it, but it basically identifies another problem with the OP's question.

Comment: @SvenMarnach right, although I think the entire question will be moot once OP understands `super`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, can't edit the comment anymore, but I've removed the -1 :).

Answer (score 1):

To do something close to what you want as opposed to an alternative approach, you can use something like this:

```
CLASS_TEMPLATE = """
class {name}(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super({name}, self).__init__('{name}')
"""

def main():
    name = "SimplePhysicsObject"
    exec CLASS_TEMPLATE.format(name=name)
    print locals()[name]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is valid for Python 2.7. (Seeing as you're using the old `super()` syntax.) If you're using Python 3.2, you could look at the implementation of [`collections.namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections.namedtuple#collections.namedtuple) that also creates classes dynamically to see how to use the new [`exec()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=exec#exec) function.

An important point is that this isn't really a macro, it won't expand into a class definition before the "compiler" processes it. It will return a new `type` object, it's up to you to make sure it goes into the right namespace.

Comment: @Ockonal To be fair, Sven's approach is more likely to do what you want if you're going to set up an inheritance hierarchy, and you only need this for logging. (As opposed to generating lots and lots of similar classes for some reason.)

Answer (score 0):

You could do exactly that, have the `DoTemplate` function return a new instantiated class and you can get the class name from the Objects `__class__` string.

Answer (score 0):

i think MacroPy is what you're looking for:
https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#case-classes